# How to check wether or not a method is called by a child?

Tags: java, android

The child Class extends a parent Class.
The parent Class has some code I don't want to execute in `onCreate()`.

How can I do this?

Parent:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!child)
        {
                ... more code ...
        }
    }
}
```

Child:

```
public class SingleArticulo extends MainActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_articulo);

        ... other code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. When you override the method and the child's object executes it, it will execute the overriden method, not the parent's one.

Comment: @aquiros: note the `super.onCreate()` there.  It is required, by the Android framework, to call `AppCompatActivity.onCreate()` and so the parent class' method must be called.

Comment: @dsh You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

Base class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.doMoreOnCreate()
    }

    protected void doMoreOnCreate() {
                ... more code ...
    }
}
```

Child:

```
public class SingleArticulo extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_articulo);

        ... other code ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void doMoreOnCreate() {
    }
}
```